# Can't load a kernel extention (.kext file) in OS X (does not contain code for architecture:x86_64 error)

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel-extension

I am trying to load a kernel extension file (.kext) to the OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.3).  I rebuilt it with XCode 4.6.1.  However, when I tried to load it with "kextutil -n -t /xxxx.kext", I got the following warning.

> Executable does not contain code for architecture: 
>          x86_64

It seems the code doesn't support x86_64, but I did include x86_64 in build settings wherever seems applicable, e.g., Valid Architectures: i386, x86_64.

How should I change the settings to make it loadable with 64-bit kernel?

Comment: hmmm. this seems like an over-zealous close to me, since it may relate to software tools.

Comment: selecting a 64-bit architecture in project/ target build setting will help.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO as mentioned in [Kernel Extension Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptKEXT/kext_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002365-BABJHCJA) ("Create a New Project" -> 6)?

Comment: Yes, I did set that to "NO"

Comment: Hm. And would it say if you'll set only x86_64 as valid architecture?